# Could running laborious code for many hours damage my mac?

Tags: mac

I'm building a deep neural network, which will take a long time to train. It's just started training and I can see that there will be roughly 7.5 hours of run-time, and my computer is making quite some noise and is heating up.

Could this damage my computer if I leave it to run? (I'll also have *Caffeine* switched on to stop the laptop from going to sleep.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, make sure your computer is on a solid surface with space around it to permit a good flow of air.

If you can have it in a cool room instead of a warm room would help.

A computer getting warm when working hard is not a problem, but if it gets too hot is - so you should check the temperatures if possible - a fan control program is a possibility.

One other possibility may be to pause the running program and allow the computer to cool down but this may not be possible...

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately not possible to pause it! I'll make sure my window is open. Do you think it would be good to raise the back by wedging a book underneath?

Comment: That may help, as long as the book does not block the fan port... no harm in trying.

Comment: If it's a command line process, surely you can temporarily suspend it by pressing ctrl-Z? A quick Google should reveal how to resume it once the laptop is cool.